# SharePoint Validation formula

Tags: custom-list

SP2013

I have single text field as part of a list and I need some validation setting up on it

The field has a default value of Unknown. The user can also input values such as 12345678-02.

The validation will be that the value in the field can be Unknown or if it is not Unknown the 9th character must be a dash i.e. -, as in the example above.

Any suggestion on how to do this are welcome - Thanks

Comment: What is the exact format you're looking for? Is it 8 Digits, followed by a dash, followed by 2 digits? Are other options possible, or is this the only allowed format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work...

```
=OR( [yourcolumn]="Unknown", MID( [yourcolumn], 9, 1 ) = "-" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work if you're wanting an exact system...

```
=OR(AND([myColumnName]="Unknown",LEN([myColumnName])=7),AND(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("????????-??",[myColumnName],1))),LEN([myColumnName])=11,NOT(ISERROR(1*CONCATENATE(MID([myColumnName],1,8),MID([myColumnName],10,2))))))
```

This validation formula requires the column to be either:

- `Unknown`, 7 characters long
- In the form `12345678-02`, 11 characters long, all digits except for the 9th character which must be a dash.

### The breakdown:

1. `AND([myColumnName]="Unknown",LEN([myColumnName])=7)`

This command is checking if the column's contents match the value "Unknown" and making sure there's no extra characters trailing, as the Validation rules sometimes put an `*` after each request to reduce the number of `and` commands. The asterisk matches anything *after* the queried string, so checking the length allows you to prevent the chance of people putting `UnknownChickens` into the field instead of just `Unknown`.

2. `ISERROR(SEARCH("????????-??",[myColumnName],1))`

This command is kind of like Regex (regular expressions) and check the column's value for "Any 8 characters, followed by a dash, followed by any two characters". The 1 there just says "Start at the beginning of the string when searching"

3. `LEN([myColumnName])=11`

Making sure the string is exactly 11 characters long.

4. NOT(ISERROR(1*CONCATENATE(MID([myColumnName],1,8),MID([myColumnName],10,2))))`

This concatenates all the spots that are supposed to be digits (your `12345678` and `02`) and multiplies them by 1. If there are any non-digit characters inside then it is invalid. That causes an error which makes `ISERROR` true, and when inverting (`NOT`) the response, results in a false. Otherwise it returns a number, `ISERROR` returns false, because the maths function worked, and inverting that results in a true expression.

(Referencing the numbers above for the `AND` and `OR` commands...)

5.`=OR([1],AND([2],[3],[4]))`

The outer function, stated above, makes sure sections 2, 3, and 4 are all true (That is the function is in the form ????????-??, all digits with one dash at position 9, and is no longer than 11 characters) **OR** section 1 is true (Column is "Unknown" and only 7 characters long).

Comment: I also tested this on SharePoint 2013, and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for this - this solved another list I have with exact characters

Comment: @KGlasier Good explanation that should be appreciated!